# Continuous Integration with VSTS

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying  to do a PoC on how to achieve continuous integration and deployment using VSTS.
I have been successful in the build process i.e. from VSTS it will pull the code (asp.net based application) and build. The build process is also getting successful. 
Now after the build is done I want to deploy the application and run my maven based selenium test cases written in java on the application. This is the part where I am struck. As in the deployment step it is not able to put the artifacts to the remote path that I am mentioning.
Can anyone please provide me some pointers on how to achieve the deployment on a remote machine and then run the java based test cases on this application?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Ok..here is the complete scenario...
1. I have the asp.net code on cloud in my vsts
2. I have been able to add a build step and create the artifacts successfully
3. Now I have a IIS server where i want to deploy these artifacts, and the server is not accessible from the public network and is behind a firewall.

Hence I am looking for any task that would help me achieve this. I am not sure of the complications that might arise due to the firewall and hence am trying out different methods to understand the complete big picture.
I received a reply here to use the Win RM tasks. I used that but it is giving a 53 error and not able to connect to the server that I am trying to deploy the code on.

Comment: Which deployment method you want to use to deploy the artifact to remote path?

Comment: Could you provide the details of your scenario?

Comment: Try looking at Deployment Groups that have recently been added to VSTS. They should solve your problem of your server being behind a firewall because VSTS agent is running on your server and is polling for tasks from VSTS master.

Answer (score -1):

To deploy asp.net based application, you can use [IIS Web App Deployment step/task to deploy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp) to your server or deploy to azure web site by using [Azure App Service Deploy step/task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps).

To do Java test, there is a [Maven step/task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Maven).